# Match character vectors in R

Tags: r

I have 2 character vectors in R.

```
a <- c("data")
b <- c("DFS", "DATa", "GFEE")
```

Can we compare vector a with b and extract a string that is there in b which matches a.
For example, a has "data", its matching vector in b is "DATa", so It should return "DATa" from vector b. In case a has "DaTa", then also it should return "DATa" since it is a match

Comment: Define what *match* means

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
b[tolower(b) %in% tolower(a)]
# [1] "DATa"
```